# "Unexpected error" when download JavaME application

Tags: java-me

When I go on my phone, and type the url to my custom JavaME application, it says "Download". Then I click "Yes". It downloads about 2/3 and then it says `Unexpected Error` and then quits. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could probably be many things, but in the past when I've experienced that particular scenario, it has usually been because of unsupported JAD/MANIFEST attributes.
For example, Nokia has invented a lot of their own attributes you can add for some of their devices. So you'd think that any Nokia-specific JAD/MANIFEST attribute will work on any Nokia phone, or at least be ignored if it's not supported - but that's not the case.
If you try installing a JAR with a MANIFEST that has certain attributes not supported, then it will come up with an install error.
If I were use I'd try removing all special attributes - even if the attribute logically should work - and see if that helps.